# Why Doctrine persist array to null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, serialization

I've added array of roles to the user entity, but can't persist it to postgreSQL.
I've tried:

```
  /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

with
 roles json NOT NULL


and

  /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $roles = [];

with
 roles VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

But all the time get an error of not null violation, so doctrine serialize it to null.

Update:
Turned out that I was using simple doctrine annotation reader and this particular column I copied from symfony example and because of `@ORM` part it just ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable= false)
  */
private $roles = [];
```